# Theory - Laravel framework, jQuery mobile template with Android and iOS Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, laravel-4, push-notification

I apologise in advance that this isn't a technical question, more of a theoretical one.

I want to build an application for Android and iOS users, using PHP (Laravel 4), and jQuery mobile as the template.

The user can enter their search criteria, and upon myself entering new products that 'fit' their criteria, they'll get a notification to their phone.

My question is, can I implement push notifications on such devices, through Laravel? If so, do you have any recommended guides / tutorials / services that I should be looking into?

The Laravel development won't be a problem, it's the push notifications! I am aware of Phonegap, Parse etc.. but it's all overwhelming! So many different services!

I understand about the device having to register etc..., but logic such as 'if user is Android...' else ... makes me lose hair!

If you require any further information, please just let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow late answer srry :)

If I understand the question correct. this is what I found after some quick research:
https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS
http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html

checking on what device the user is, can be done via this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
this is all based on some simple research and my understanding of your question. hoped it helped :)